# Функция comment_form() не работает (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Я пытаюсь добавить форму комментариев в шаблон страницы, однако, по неясным мне причинам она не появляется. Я не знаю, почему, потому что вроде бы делаю всё верно. Сниппет файла **reviews.php**:

```
    <?php 
    /*
     * Template Name: Reviews
     */
     get_header(); ?>
    <div class="container page">
        <h2>Отзывы</h2>

        <?php


        comments_template();


    ?>

    <?php comment_form();?>

    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

В итоге имеем на выходе:
    [image: скриншот на выходе]
    Т.е. формы комментариев под самими комментариями нет, а с выводом комментов всё ок. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему нет формы?

Структура самописной темы Wordpress:
    [image: структура темы]

Ну и на всякий случай, содержимое файла **comments.php**:

```
    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <ol class="comment-list">
            <?php
                wp_list_comments( array(
                    'style'       => 'ol',
                    'short_ping'  => true,
                    'avatar_size' => 74,
                ) );
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

        <?php
            // Are there comments to navigate through?
            if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) :
        ?>
        <nav class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="screen-reader-text section-heading"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav><!-- .comment-navigation -->
        <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation ?>

        <?php if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

Comment: Не уверен, но не связано ли это с тем что форма отображается только для авторизованных пользователей?

Comment: в данном случае, был авторизирован (на скрин хедер не вошёл).
попробовал неавторизированным - то же самое

Comment: Проверьте настройки, возможно, комментарии просто отключены в админке. Попробуйте вызвать функцию `comment_form()` ниже `comments_template()`, если убедились в том, что комментарии разрешены, а форма всё равно не выводится